# Retrofit асинхронные вызовы

Tags: java, android, retrofit

Использую асинхронные вызовы. И у меня возник вопрос. Я использую `ProgressDialog`. Дело в том что, если один вызов, то он идеально работает. А если я вызываю несколько, то он закрывает после первого.  Понятно что благодаря этому коду      `dialog.dismiss();`. Как сделать так, чтоб все запросы привязать к одному  `ProgressDialog`. Если какие фрагменты кода надо, пишите скину.

```
 public void generateYkrepClan(ApiService api, final ProgressDialog dialog, final String id_clan) {

    Call<ResponseBody> call = api.getYkrepClan(id_clan, application_id);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
            dialog.dismiss();

            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                try {
                    list = response.body().string();
                    Log.e("EWQ", list);
                    clan_dannie.setYkrep(generateDannieClan.getYkrep(list));
                   // clan_dannie.setDannieCoklanovzas(generateDannieClan.generatePersonallyDanieClan(list, dannieClanNew));
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else {
                Snackbar.make(parentView, "kek", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться [RxJava](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava)

**Api.java**

```
public interface Api {
    @GET("/api.php")
    Flowable<Response<ResponseBody>> getYkrepClan(/**/);
}
```

Простой запрос

```
Flowable<Response<ResponseBody>> firstFlowable = api.getYkrepClan(id_clan, application_id);
```

Два последовательных запроса:

```
Flowable<Response<ResponseBody>> flowable = firstFlowable 
    .concatWith(api.anotherRequest());
```

Два параллельных запроса:

```
Flowable<Response<ResponseBody>> flowable = firstFlowable 
    .mergeWith(api.anotherRequest());
```

Второй запрос на основе результата из первого:

```
Flowable<Response<ResponseBody>> flowable = firstFlowable 
    .flatMap(new Function<Response<ResponseBody>, Flowable<? extends Response<ResponseBody>>>() {
        @Override
        public Flowable<? extends Response<ResponseBody>> apply(Response<ResponseBody> response) throws Exception {
            Log.d("TAG", response.body().string());
            return api.anotherRequest(response.body().string());
        }
    })
```

Выполнить:

```
flowable 
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribe(new FlowableSubscriber<Response<ResponseBody>>() {
        @Override
        public void onSubscribe(Subscription s) {
            //Показать диалог
            s.request(Long.MAX_VALUE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onNext(Response<ResponseBody> responseBodyResponse) {
            //Прилетел ответ
            Log.d("TAG",response.body().string());
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable t) {
            //Ошибка
        }

        @Override
        public void onComplete() {
           //Убрать диалог
        }
    });
```

Comment: Я бы вместо ```Flowable``` посоветовал использовать ```Single```, т.к. сервер возвращает один ответ, а в для ситуаций когда ожидается только один результат лучше подходит ```Single```

Comment: @temq, абсолютно верно

Comment: Вопрос наверно глупый, и всё же меня очень сильно интересует. Вот тут вы показываете пример использования параллельных запросов, а как обработать эти данные. Как понять какой ответ куда подходит

Comment: @ВиталийРобиновский, думаю нужно будет обернуть результаты, а у обертки завести поле type какое нибудь.

Comment: А по конкретней можно, не совсем понимаю, как это можно сделать

Comment: @ВиталийРобиновский, я придумал получше, 
 этот метод `response.raw().request().url()` вернет `url` с которого сделан запрос.

Comment: Спасибо, попробую. Вы тут показали пример где второй запрос выполняется  на основе  результат первого,  можно прикрутить  к ним асинхронные запросы (чтоб тоже выполнялись) совместно с теми двумя

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58043/discussion-between-katso-and--).

Comment: спасибо, это помогло мне