# Два AsyncTask в одном классе одновременно исполняются в одном потоке

Tags: java, android

Делал обработку фотографий в Renderscript, но он ведет себя очень нестабильно (на C99), через раз работает. Но так как обычная обработка идет долго решил разбить изображения по частям и обрабатывать в разных потоках одновременно. Но обнаружил что два AsyncTask обрабатываются почему то по очереди один за другим , а не одновременно как например два потока в  Thread (Thread не использую так как пока не знаю как передавать потом Bitmap между потоками). Это нормальное поведение двух дочерних AsyncTask в одном классе? Или они должны в разных потоках все-таки работать?

Comment: [о параллельной работе AsyncTask в Android](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/424762/177345)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Это нормальное поведение двух дочерних AsyncTask в одном классе?

Да, это дефолтное поведение.

Изначально `AsyncTask` работали последовательно, потом, с версии 1.6 они начали работать параллельно, далее, с 3.0 их поведение изменили и сделали их выполнение снова последовательным, однако это поведение можно изменить:

```
myAsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
```

При старте `AsyncTask` таким образом, они будут работать параллельно.

Answer (score 1):

Я бы вам по рекомендовал бы использовать библиотеку [RxJava](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava). Тут не надо использовать AsyncsTask и мучатся в этом коде. Тут в вопросе есть хороший ответ, показывает как работать   [Пример RxJava](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/660648/retrofit-%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%85%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B)

Comment: Retrofit предполагает совершенно другой паттерн программирования и не всегда может быть применим, так что ваш ответ не всегда верен.

Comment: Вы абсолютно правы

Answer (score 1):

Как говорит нам документация:

> When first introduced, AsyncTasks were executed serially on a single background thread. Starting with DONUT, this was changed to a pool of threads allowing multiple tasks to operate in parallel. Starting with HONEYCOMB, tasks are executed on a single thread to avoid common application errors caused by parallel execution.
>
> If you truly want parallel execution, you can invoke executeOnExecutor(java.util.concurrent.Executor, Object[]) with THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR.

То есть надо делать так (с учетом конечно, вышесказанных ограничений):

```
asyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, params);
```

**Update:**

Можно еще и по другому:

```
AsyncTaskCompat.executeParallel(asyncTask, params);
```

Правда он депрекирован начиная с API=26 (я лично по старинке запускаю именно так).